# model.find() return empty in a function while works properly outside the function?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I encountered a problem when using Mongoose in a nodejs express app.

app.js:

```
model.find(function(err,result){
  console.log("testfind1：",result);
})//works properly


wss.on('connection',function(ws) {  
    ws.on('message',function message(msg){  
      model.find(function(err,result){
        console.log("testfind2：",result);
      })//returns empty array
    })
})
```

The code above are all in the same .js file, and the result1 is correct while result2 is empty.

Why?

Comment: From the code, I understood you created a socket connect. When message event is triggered, you are doing db query. What is the error?. Check if the code is reaching inside the message event

Comment: The error is, the query outside the websocket event is correct while copy the same query into the websocket event will just return an empty result:(  By the way the query outside sometimes wont work, if I restart the app.js for one or two times, it will return the correct result, but the query inside the event always wont work...

Comment: please specify more details -  why the query outside is not working sometimes. Please provide entire app.js and db config details